# ad filtring software - how does it work?

Tags: multiprocessing, cpu

It is known that one process can not access another process memory area.
Yet, anti filtering software like Ad-Muncher do affect other software like FireFox or Chrome and making them not to show specific context.

How could it be done if these anti filtering software can not access the memory of the browser? better yet in order for it to work the anti filtering software needs to be be running on the CPU before the browser lunch the site... if not, the browser will show AD which was not filtering.

I know i'm missing something but can't find out what...
How these software works? I'm not interested in detailed algorithm... just the general idea.

Please note that my question **isn't** about AD-Blocker and other browser ad-ons which sit inside the browser and get full access to it's data and stack.

Comment: when you install it it notes "this will have full access to everything". Does that not help?

Comment: It can note anything it wants but the fact is that when it runs, it's a process.. and it can not alter other process like the browser. I think filtering is based on something else.. just can't figure out what.

Comment: Think of it as a pipeline. The page is presented to the plugin. What the plugin allows through is rendered as the webpage.

Comment: Hi paul... I specified my question to Non plug in software... like Ad-Muncher... it's unrelated to the browser.

Comment: oh, well, presumably when it installs you give it admin access. It can then do what it likes, including installing hooks to give it access to incoming connectinos etc.

Comment: so it's monitoring the communication and change it before the data is being deliverer to the browser?

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to filter ads from websites, but probably the best approach is to be a "[forward proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server)", that way all the http/https traffic is going through your software without any hassle.

All modern browsers and operating systems support that.

You can use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for example, just download it and you will see all the traffic that goes to your browser, fiddler can also modify the traffic.

Of course the most important part is to understand which part of the html is ad and which is actual content wanted by the user.

About your question of how one software can access another software memory area, you can start here :
[How is it possible to access memory of other processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989783/how-is-it-possible-to-access-memory-of-other-processes)